# Uma função de uma DLL do Windows tem o mesmo endereço?

Tags: windows, dll

Estou com uma duvida uma função de uma DLL do windows tem sempre o mesmo endereço para todas as versões ou ela é dinâmica?

Exemplo uma função da `user32.dll`.

Esse trecho do Wikipedia responde minha pergunta. O endereço que estava me referindo é o endereço dos bytes localizado dentro da DLL, o endereço da função em tempo de execução ela dinâmica.

Pode-se editar o código de máquina usando editores hexadecimais, como
por exemplo o "debug" que roda sobre o DOS do Windows. Com estes
programas pode-se ver o código não em binário, mas em hexadecimal,
como mostrado abaixo nesta captura da tela do DOS com o *debug* aberto
editando o programa "v.exe": (tecla-se ? para comandos e d para *dump*)

```
C:\Utility>debug v.exe
-d 0 100
0E3D:0000  CD 20 FF 9F 00 9A F0 FE-1D F0 4F 03 F0 07 8A 03   . ........O.....
0E3D:0010  F0 07 17 03 F0 07 DF 07-01 01 01 00 02 FF FF FF   ................
0E3D:0020  FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF-FF FF FF FF BD 0D 4C 01   ..............L.
0E3D:0030  D0 0C 14 00 18 00 3D 0E-FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 00   ......=.........
0E3D:0040  05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
0E3D:0050  CD 21 CB 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 20 20 20   .!...........
0E3D:0060  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20-00 00 00 00 00 20 20 20           .....
0E3D:0070  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00           ........
0E3D:0080  00 0D 76 2E 65 78 65 0D-44 4F 57 53 5C 73 79 73   ..v.exe.DOWS\sys
0E3D:0090  74 65 6D 33 32 5C 64 6F-73 78 0D 0D 64 61 20 72   tem32\dosx..da r
0E3D:00A0  65 64 65 20 28 63 61 72-72 65 67 61 72 20 61 6E   ede (carregar an
0E3D:00B0  74 65 73 20 64 6F 20 64-6F 73 78 2E 65 78 65 29   tes do dosx.exe)
```

No exemplo acima é mostrado à esquerda o endereço da memória
(*segmento:offset*), ao centro o código em hexadecimal e à direita como
seria o texto em ASCII. Mais eficiente do que tudo isso seria
conseguir um programa dedicado para manipulação de código de máquina.

Comment: Você quer dizer o endereço que ela é mapeada em memória? Ou a posição da função dentro da `dll`?

Comment: por exemplo a dll user32.dll e uma função qualquer. no sistema quando eu quero pega o endereço dessa função ela é statica ou dinamica?
ela pode variar dependendo da versão do windows?

Comment: se eu pega o endereço da função GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle('user32.DLL'),'ShowWindow')  ela me retorna sempre o mesmo endereço da função . eu nao sei te dizer ao certo, pq minha duvida é essa. mas pelo que voce falou tenho quase certeza que é  a posição da função dentro.

Comment: achei no wikipedia mas queria uma explicação melhor{
Cada função exportada por uma DLL é identificada por um numeral ordinal e, opcionalmente, um nome. Similarmente, as funções podem ser importadas da DLL tanto pelo numeral quanto pelo nome}

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 1):

Esqueça o endereço da função. Ele é variável e não importa. O fato de mostrar o mesmo é uma coincidência e não pode ser usada como algo garantido. Você só tem que saber qual função quer usar e na maioria dos casos que DLL ela está para carregá-la. Só isto.

O mais importante sobre pegar o endereço você já sabe. Se fosse fixo não precisaria de uma função para isto.

Só informações documentadas. O que não está documentado, pode mudar sem que você saiba.

O endereço naquele momento só importa em questões mais avançadas.

A pergunta mudou, mas a informação permanece a mesma. Não dá para confiar no endereço da função e não tem porque fazer isto. Quando se precisa do endereço dela é só pedir ao sistema operacional que ele diz onde está o endereço com [`GetProcAddress()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getprocaddress?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Comment: mas o endereço da posição da função dentro da dll ela pode mudar?

Comment: A função predispõe de endereços diferentes, Uma função não pode ser executada num mesmo endereço, Até porque não é só uma library que vai ser usada normalmente.

Comment: Não sei do que você está falando ou da relevância disto. Se precisa de informação adicional, explique o quer.

Comment: amigo se voce abri a dll em um editor hexadecimal voce vai ver o endereço de cada instrução, é essa posição que estou me referindo ...
como o amigo ali em cima disse estou querendo dizer é o endereço da função mapeada dentro da dll a posição no editor hexadecimal

Comment: Não, você não vê endereço algum lá. Agora estou achando que esta pergunta sequer é de programação. O Mega está falando de outra coisa. Se não conseguir esclarecer melhor qual é a dúvida, vou fechar a pergunta. No máximo você que em que sequência de *bytes* o código está no arquivo. Isto não é relevante para programação e não é algo confiável. A resposta já fala isto.

Comment: como não é relevante para programação ? estou tentando esclarece minha pergunta, e como voce agora disse é a sequencia de bytes que esta no arquivo que estou me referido , essa sequencia pode ser alterada em tempo de execução ?

Comment: conseguir sanar minha duvida , o endereço ele é dinâmico na verdade é os bytes que to me referindo dentro da dll , em tempo de execução

Comment: e existe sim endereço dos bytes que ele é localizado sem mais !

Comment: Acho que a DLL pode especificar um "endereço predileto" que acelera a carga do programa se não houver conflitos, mas nada garante que o endereço não será realocado.